# cannot contain "Catalina sh not working in java devel"

Tags: docker, devops, redhat

i am using dockerfile

```
FROM redhat/ubi8
MAINTAINER "Devil@gmail.com"
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install java-devel -y
RUN yum install unzip  -y
RUN mkdir /server
COPY Dockerfile /server
COPY apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz /server
WORKDIR /server
ADD apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz /server
RUN tar xfh /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz
CMD ["/server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19/bin/catalina.sh","run"]
EXPOSE 8080 8085 8081
```

In this file docker build is successful but facing error at the time of container build

```
# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
49ca5c2108bb   cc606115c681   "/server/apache-tomc…"   11 seconds ago   Exited (1) 10 seconds ago             t1
[root@ip-devil. ~]# docker logs 49ca5c2108bb
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19/bin/bootstrap.jar:/server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:
Unrecognised option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

please suggest how to solve and run the container

Comment: Take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129952/jdk10-message-note-picked-up-jdk-java-options describing where that `--add-opens` comes from and what its intent is. I suspect your JVM may be too old to support the new options, in which case the most straightforward solution might be to use a base image with a newer JVM.

Comment: BTW, why did you add the curly brackets? The link you were given says to use the `{}` button in the editor -- meaning click the button having that label with the mouse inside Stack Overflow's editing GUI while the code to format is selected -- not to add `{` and `}` characters as text; but you don't need to do either, because I already fixed the code formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `openjdk` image since it already has the Java development environment. Also download the Apache Tomcat distribution rather than using a local copy.

```
FROM openjdk:23-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -q wget

WORKDIR /server

RUN wget -q https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.19/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz && \
    tar xfh /server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19.tar.gz

CMD ["/server/apache-tomcat-10.1.19/bin/catalina.sh","run"]
```